# How to support added frameworks for iOS >= 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My iOS App's minimum OS requirement is `iOS 6+.`

But if I add required frameworks, it asks for iOS 7+ SDK, and gives an error message.

But I don't want to give up iOS 6 users, have any best solution?

How to support iOS 6+ for all frameworks?

Currently I have Xcode version 7.3.1 Base SDK 9.3

I try this code but still doesn't work.

```
#if __IPHONE_7_0
// Works on >= version 7.0
#else
 // Works on < version 7.0
#endif
```

Comment: You want user to restrict user from doing something or you want your app to run only on IOS >= 7

Comment: Which framework are you adding that requires iOS 7?

Comment: Hi There, the framework is Facebook Audience Network